# When does Firestore's instance singleton serve subsequent document requests up from memory?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, caching, firebase-authentication, provider

Is there a best practice on how to serve up singleton-like session data? I'd prefer to retrieve the `user` record once in the beginning and then always get the same record back from memory whenever I am referencing it, similar to how Firebase Auth offers its data:

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

After authentication, `auth.currentUser!.uid` can be referenced anywhere and is clearly accessing the local cache of data relating to the authenticated user.

There is somewhat ambiguous language all over the Firestore docs about local caching, but I'm wondering if/when requesting a document is hitting an in-memory cache vs. going across the Internet to Firebase in order to serve a record that has already been retrieved prior.

For example, take a mock user document...

```
user
- email
```

And after successfully exiting an authentication flow...

1. Use `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').user(authUserId).get()` to retrieve a record from Firestore collection `user` for a document identified by the now-logged-in user, `authUserId`.
2. Other places in the application / widget tree, additionally use `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').user(authUserId).get()` to fetch the same record in order to access `user.email`.

Is this two queries over the internet? Or 1 to the internet and then 1 local?

Comment: There's a lot of room for misinterpretation here, and Firestore's SDKs work differently across platforms and across certain API calls (both by design). Can you show a real [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that calls the actual Firestore API to load (and process) data?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi Frank, I've attempted to add more concrete detail and reorganized the question to hopefully better articulate what my goal is first and what curiosities it generated second. Hope this makes it clear?

Comment: To elaborate a little more, I was about to embark on figuring out how to create a singleton to store the retrieved user record so that it can be universally accessed (like Firebase auth does), but wanted to first come here to see if there's a smarter way to go about it. C/C++ taught me to shudder when thinking 'singleton' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the device is connected, both `get()` calls will end up going to the server as the document may have changed between the calls.

If you want to prevent the second call going to the server, you can [pass `GetOptions`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/get.html) to the call.

Comment: Got it. I see the option for specifying the `Source` as `cache`.